# Displaying images uploaded to s3 in the frontend - security

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I'm uploading images to `s3`, saving the absolute URLs in my database, and then displaying them in my frontend. There are two problems I see - the first one is that I need to mark them as public while uploading:

```
$path = $image->storeAs('folder', md5('file_name.jpg'), ['disk' => 's3']);
Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($path, 'public');
$url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);
```

The second problem is that the URLs I use in the website have the bucket name in it obviously, for example:

```
<img src="https://bucket-name-staging.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/folder/84b4b3j4j34j12j3123h21jh321k312312.jpg">
```

This also makes it blocked by adblock sometimes. Is this the recommended way to do it? Can I display images on the website if they are private in the `s3` bucket? (I tried it - but that's a `403` response).

Answer (score 0):

As for first question, please check the following approaches mentioned here:

- [Upload files Securely to AWS S3](https://medium.com/@ashan.fernando/upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-signed-urls-fa0a0cf489db)
- [Uploading Photos to Amazon S3 from a Browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html)

As for second problem, please check:

- Route 53
- CloudFront(is needed if you would like to load files by https)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pure HTML code to show the s3 images on your website there is no way else flagging them as public, but in this case, those files will be available for all people around the world and they can show your images and absolutely you will be charged or using signed url, but you are using PHP you can try [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html)